# msal.acquire_token_by_username_password to get access token having issues with scope

Tags: django, testing, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to access a User's token using username of password, but I have an issue with the scope

```
class AuthenticatedURLTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.journal_list_url = reverse('journalentry:journalcomptable_list',  args=["slug_group", "slug_app"])
        
        
        self.username = os.getenv('TEST_USER_EMAIL') 
        self.password = os.getenv('TEST_USER_PASSWORD') 
        self.auth0_client_id = os.getenv('ADD_B2C_CLIENT_ID')
        self.auth0_client_secret = os.getenv('ADD_B2C_CLIENT_SECRET')
        self.auth0_api_identifier = os.getenv('ADD_B2C_SUSI_AUTHORITY')
        self.auth0_api_scope = os.getenv('ADD_B2C_SCOPE')
        
        

        app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
            client_id=os.getenv("ADD_B2C_CLIENT_ID"),
            authority=os.getenv("ADD_B2C_SUSI_AUTHORITY")
        )

        result = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(
        username=os.getenv('TEST_USER_EMAIL'),
        password=os.getenv('TEST_USER_PASSWORD'),
        scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/offline_access','https://graph.microsoft.com/openid']
        )
       

       if "access_token" in result:
            self.token = result["access_token"]
            print(self.token)
            print("got access token")
        else:
            print(result.get("error_description") or result.get("error"))
        
    def test_authenticated_url(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.journal_list_url,HTTP_AUTHORIZATION="Bearer " + self.token)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I am getting the error :

```
The orchestration step '1' does not specify a CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId when one was expected.
Timestamp: 2023-05-10 09:51:38Z
```

How do I modify the scope to get the access token ?